# ESLint Sorting RegEx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, eslint

I am using the `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` package to sort my imports, and have custom defined `rules` in my `.eslintrc.json`'s `overrides` section for `simple-import-sort/imports`'s `groups`.

My question pertains to sorting order as it comes to named imports and default imports. The default sorting right now is based on package name and/or path name, based on my defined rules.

Right now the below sorted group looks like this:

```js
import chatSystem from 'utils/chat-system';
import FirebaseUtils from 'utils/firebase';
import * as Imgix from 'utils/imgix';
import LinkHelper from 'utils/link-helper';
import { SOME_CONSTANT, someMethod } from 'utils/orders';
```

What I would like to do is order these sorted imports to look like this:

```js
import chatSystem from 'utils/chat-system';
import FirebaseUtils from 'utils/firebase';
import LinkHelper from 'utils/link-helper';
import * as Imgix from 'utils/imgix';
import { SOME_CONSTANT, someRandomMethod } from 'utils/orders';
```

Where default imports are first, followed by `* as` imports, and lastly, named destructured imports.

Does anyone know if this is possible, like with RegEx rules, without the need for a custom ESLint rule...?

For reference, here are some relevant pieces of my `.eslintrc.json` config (*with unrelated pieces omitted for clarity*):

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:import/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"],
  "rules": {
    "import/order": "off",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js"],
      "rules": {
        "simple-import-sort/imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": [
              ["^react$", "react-redux", "^react-router", "redux", "^redux-"],
              ["^@", "^\\w"],
              ["^(actions)"],
              ["^(actions)(/.*)(types)"],
              ["^(reducers)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(selectors)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(components)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(containers)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(hooks)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(constants)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(utils)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^(config)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^\\.\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\.\\./?$"],
              ["^\\./(?=.*/)(?!/?$)", "^\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\./?$"],
              ["^.+\\.?(s?css)$"],
              ["^\\u0000"]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```